# Javascript ou Jquery, evento onblur

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Bom dia, estou querendo atualizar o banco de dados com a informação que eu digito no input,  assim que esse input perde o focus com onblur quero ele mande o dados para a página php que irá fazer o update no banco de dados. exemplo abaixo.

```
 <input type="text" size="2" id="n1" onblur="" value="<?=$aln->n1?>"></td>
```

Desde já Agradeço.

Comment: existe a necessidade de não enviar os dados em um form? ja testou via ajax?

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, não estou usando form, estou usando uma tabelas na qual eu coloco a nota do aluno que é nota1.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, boa tarde, existem algumas formas de fazer isso, mas vamos utilizar as funções [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) e [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) da biblioteca jQuery, pois é uma das formas mais simples e fácil de se fazer isso.
A função blur é disparada quando aquele determinado input perde o foco, justamente como queremos. Já a função Ajax serve para executar solicitações assíncronas ao servidor de maneira simples. Veja:

```js
$(documentos).ready(function (){
    $("#n1").blur(function (){
        var valor = $(this).val(); // pega o valor do campo

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "servidor.php", // Seu servidor 
           data: {valorInput: valor} // Envia o post valorInput para o servidor
        });
    });
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!